# How to prevent headphones from getting entangled?

Tags: technology, comfort, headphones

As a lot of people, I am using headphones daily in order to listen music, as I don't plan to buy bluetooth one, I was wondering if you had any lifehacks to prevent them from getting **tangled** everytime I put them on my pocket or in a bag.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After use:

Step 1. Grab both earbuds.

[image: step 1]

Step 2. Use your opposite hand to wrap the chord around the fingers you gripped the earbuds with leaving around two inched unwrapped.

[image: step 2]

Step 3. Remove the headphones from the hand

Step 4. Hold the headphones with your thumb and index finger.

[image: step 4]

Step 5. Using the excess cord wrap it in the middle

Step 6. Stick the last inch of the cord through the loop you just made. Now they're secure enough to put in your bag without getting tangled.

[image: step 6]

Comment: Well... this does not work. At least in my case. I usually try to tie my headphones this way before putting into pocket, and after some time the knot looks like the one on OP's image.

Answer (score 2):

I use a plastic Ziploc bag, and leave the earbuds and the plug sticking out of the end. Then I close the "zipper" as far as it will go, leaving half an inch for the buds & plug. This prevents my cord from tangling, because none of the ends (bud #1, bud #2, or the plug) can pass through any loops in the rest of the cord.

I made a video about this years ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iV8LMekEy20